# Where are My Data Points?

Tags: plotting

I'm plotting a collection of data points `{X,Y}` with the following:

```
   N0tenthPlt = 
   ListPlot[N0tenth, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 1.0}}, ImageSize -> {800, 509.3}, 
   Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], AbsolutePointSize[10]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 2/\[Pi], 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["TIME (months)", Bold, Blue], 
     Style["HEIGHT (cms)", Bold, Blue]}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Large]];
```

My points disappeared after I added the `Joined->True` option to the code. All I see is a series of straight lines connected end to end. What do I do? Advice? Suggestions?

Comment: Add `Mesh -> All`  in your code

Comment: Or use `PlotMarkers -> Automatic`.

Answer (score 2):

`SeedRandom[123];
pts = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 10];`

```
 Grid[{{ListPlot[pts, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
Joined -> True], ListPlot[pts, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, Mesh -> All,  Joined -> True]}}]
```

[image]